# Stripe payment screen shows '$' sign instead of showing '£' for transaction

Tags: stripe-payments

i am working on a website for which i used stripe payment gateway for payments. Currently it is in testing mode where, i click on make payment button screen/modal of stripe API calling occurs. In that modal the amount displayed is with currency 'usd' I need it to be in 'gbp'.

My code is:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
        class="stripe-button" 
        data-key="pk_test_StWym8ABLxbLhtwU5LIjJxtj" 
        data-image="files/images/GO_TUTOR_ICON_NEW.png" 
        data-name="Gotutor Payment" 
        data-description="Tutor Transaction"
        data-amount="<?php echo $_GET['planTotal']; ?>" />
</script>
```

The transaction amount it shows is in $. I want it to show in '£'

How to make it. Is there any extra parameter to add in the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to `data-currency="gbp"` to the list of [configuration options](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple-options).

Comment: oh! thanks that link is simply awesome. i got what i need.

Comment: I have a query, when i debug the api response i am not getting the email, provided by the user who does the transaction. How do i get that?

Comment: You should receive the email in a separate POST parameter, `stripeEmail` rather than `stripeToken`.